# How to add options to the menu item that is asosiated with your component.

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I Have created a component in Joomla 2.5, I have succesfully installed it, and now I need to add some options that will be configured at the menu view. So when a user ads a new menu item to a menu and the menu type is my component, then he can also select some parameters at the menu item view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on the first page of the docs for developing an MVC component for Joomla 2.5:

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_05

To access these params from within your component look at " Accessing the parameters - frontend" on this page:

http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters

Comment: yep thank you I was also readint his now. I was wondering how I can get the parameter now. I added the parameters that i Needed, but it seems that I cant access them from the view nor from the model for some reason. But anyway thank you I will ask again if I can't find anything else